# Web, SQLite database downloads when url is visited?

Tags: sqlite, web

I have an sqlite database located at:

```
http://example.com/db/test.db
```

When visited in a browser, the **database is downloaded**.

How can i prevent this as i do not want others to be able to get ahold of it?

Comment: what web server are you using, apache, iis, ngx or what?

Comment: Put the database somewhere outside the web root.

Comment: i'm not sure...its a godaddy linux hosting plan

Comment: ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717444/most-supported-way-to-protect-flatfiles-sqlite-db-from-http-access

Comment: It's probably apache then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like a .htaccess file, along the lines of;

```
<Files ~ "\.(htaccess|db)$">
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

Comment: will mark as answer when SO lets me, although this was also on the link martin posted. it works perfectly